# ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'

Tags: django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi, python-imaging-library

Apache or Python doesn't import image on the media folder. When I tried to upload something It returns 500 error.

Django is working behind Apache with mod_wsgi on CentOS 7. Django also works in a virtual environment. I disabled all firewalls (selinux, firewalld and iptables) I gave every permission to the Apache for the project folder. (*chown apache:apache* and *chmod 777* I applied public write permission only for the media folder)

**Here is my apache conf file for the project:**

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/html  
   Alias /static/ /var/www/example.com/html/static/
   Alias /media /var/www/example.com/html/media

    <Location "/static/">
        Options -Indexes
    </Location>

   <Directory /var/www/example.com/html/logging>
    <Files debug.log>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/html>
        <Files db.sqlite3>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/example.com/html/media>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/example.com/html/media/uploads>
      Require all granted
  </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/example.com/html/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/example.com/html/example>
        <Files wsgi.py>
             Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

   WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www/example.com/html:/var/www/example.com/html/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup example.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/example.com/html/example/wsgi.py

   #Log Settings
    ErrorLog "/etc/httpd/logs/example_error"
    CustomLog "/etc/httpd/logs/example_acess" combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from services.file_extentions import validate_image_extention

# Create your models here.
class FotografModel(models.Model):
    """Model definition for GaleriModel."""

    # TODO: Define fields here
    foto = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Fotoğraf", upload_to='uploads/fotograflar/', max_length=100, height_field=None, width_field=None, validators=[validate_image_extention])
    foto_baslik = models.CharField(verbose_name="Fotoğraf Açıklaması (Görme Engelliler için)", max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    olusturulma_tarihi = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, auto_now_add=True, null=True, verbose_name="Oluşturulma tarihi")
    guncelleme = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, auto_now_add=False, verbose_name="Son güncelleme", editable=False)

    class Meta:
        """Meta definition for FotografModel."""

        verbose_name = 'Fotoğraf'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Fotoğraflar'

    def image_tag(self):
        path = "/media/"+str(self.foto)
        return u'<img src="%s" style="height:80px!important;height:auto;"/>' % (path)

    image_tag.short_description = "Fotoğraf"
    image_tag.allow_tags = True

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.foto_baslik)

from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=FotografModel)
def fotograf_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # Pass false so FileField doesn't save the model.
    instance.foto.delete(False)
```

**debug log**

```
from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging'
```

When I open the shell in my virtual environment and tried this code `from PIL import _imaging` it works well. The project is using 4.3.0 version of Pillow package.

Comment: That error is from a very old version of PIL/Pillow. The import was changed to `from PIL import _imaging as core` [4 years ago](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/commit/7f698a6fc5f85d4e857a5e8f92a4e1c786d8d3ed). How have you configured Apache to run with Python 3? I can see that you've added the virtual env to the Python path but you haven't included any other info. Are you sure it's not running Python 2?

Comment: I have configured virtual host to run with Python3

`WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www/example.com/html:/var/www/example.com/html/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages`

Comment: As I said, that doesn't make it use Python 3, it just adds the virtualenv to the python path. I think you need to install the Python version of the mod_wsgi module. For example [in Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-16-04) you need to install `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`. I don't know what the equivalent for CentOS is.

Comment: Thank you @Alasdair. It worked. As you said, I had installed mod_wsgi for python 2. Until you said I didn't realize that. After I removed old mod_wsgi then updated it and it fixed. Would you add your comment as an answer so that people can see the solution?

Comment: Glad you got it to work. It might be better for you to answer the question yourself, because you can give specific details for CentOS.

Comment: @oyilmaztekin, can you please explain how you resolved this issue on centos. I installed mod_wsgi as "sudo yum install mod_wsgi" but still the issue is not resolved.